# Running OSGI bundle from OSGI command prompt :Import-package missing constraint

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have a bundle with the following mainfest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: HelloCamera
Bundle-SymbolicName: HelloCamera
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: hellocamera.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: cameraservice, cameraserviceimpl, org.osgi.framework

Layout:
    HelloCamera
       -> hellocamera
            -> Activator.java
```

And a second bundle with this manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: CameraService
Bundle-SymbolicName: CameraService
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Export-Package: cameraservice, cameraserviceimpl
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
Bundle-Activator: cameraserviceimpl.Activator

Layout:
    CameraService
       -> cameraservice
            -> CameraService.java
       -> cameraserviceimpl
            -> Activator.java 
            -> CameraServiceImpl.java
```

I can run the first bundle from Eclipse and everything works fine as expected. I then exported both bundles as a `CameraService.jar`  and `HelloCamera.jar` respectivly

I opened up my OSGI console, `java -jar equinox.jar -console` and

```
osgi> install file:CameraService.jar
osgi> install file:HelloCamera.jar
osgi> ss
           id    State         Bundle
           17   INSTALLED      HelloCamera_1.0.0.qualifier
           18   RESOLVED       unknown_0.0.0 [18]
```

then I get

```
The Bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: cameraservice; version="0.0.0"
```

Comment: What do you mean you exported *both* bundles as a `jar`? One `jar`, one bundle.

Comment: @chrylis i have tried exporting them together as one bundle and as two seperate bundles

Comment: Please post your manifest from the "two-`jar`" bundle. (By copying it out of the zip file, not from Eclipse.)

Comment: @chrylis how do i get the maifest from the `jar` file?

Comment: Open the `jar` in a zip utility (like WinZip) or use `jar -xf Test.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: @chrylis added it, as you can see the imports arent there :/ I assume that is what is causing the problem, any ideas on how to fix it ?

Comment: Yes, don't try to cram two bundles into a single `jar` file! Export each bundle as a `jar` and then import them together or in the proper order.

Comment: @chrylis it still is not working, giving me the same error : see the updated code ^ with OSGI output

Comment: There's something very suspicious about the second bundle. Why would OSGi report it as "resolved" but not know the name of it? I think probably the JAR file is corrupt or the manifest is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching,

I found the problem was with the manifest files. When exporting the jars in my settings I said use the manifest file already in the folder.

I never looked at what the path was pointing to (assuming eclipse would set it correctly) however Eclipse hadn't changed its location so both jars were using the same Manifest file.

Lesson learned. Always check the form before blindly pressing finish.

Comment: It sounds like you're building your bundles in  very manual and error-prone way. Why not look into using proper tooling, like bnd and Bndtools?